# Imagemagick label issue

Tags: imagemagick, label, gravity

I am using imagemagick 6.2.8 and i want to add a label at the bottom of the image aligned on the right side.

this is my code:

```
convert image.png -gravity center -background "#f0f0f0" -font bgothm.ttf -pointsize 18 label:"text text" -append "append_image.png"
```

however the label is aligned to the left

How can i align the label to the right?

Edit:
I found this: Before IM v6.4.7 it was much more difficult to align appended images, and generally involved using a "-flop" for right alignment. Or using "-extent" or "-border" to adjust the image width for centered aligned appends.
But i never used imagemagick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: I have updated my solution to work with your ImageMagick version.

Do the double -flop trick. One flop to mirror the text, so it will be right aligned and one flop to mirror the append to make it readable:

```
convert image.png -background "#f0f0f0" -font bgothm.ttf \
  -pointsize 18 label:"text text" -flop -append -flop "append_image.png"
```

Produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1LgN.jpg) image for me. Please note that the order of -flop -append -flop **do** matter!

But still, a better solution would be to upgrade ImageMagick to >= 6.4.7 and use -gravity SouthEast:

```
convert image.png -gravity SouthEast -background "#f0f0f0" -font bgothm.ttf \
  -pointsize 18 label:"text text" -append "append_image.png"
```

Answer (score 2):

To align bottom-right, [use `-gravity southeast`.](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=hshb2p7s7hv4vfenca55amab03#gravity)

```
convert image.png -gravity southeast -background "#f0f0f0" -font bgothm.ttf -pointsize 18 label:"text text" -append "append_image.png"
```